# Integration with ionic.io doesn't work on Ionic 2

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I am trying to integrate Ionic Platform (ionic.io) with my Ionic 2 application. After following the steps, it gives me an error:

`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic-platform-web-client/dist/ionic.io.bundle.min.js`

I manually copied the file `ionic.io.bundle.min.js` from `bower_componets/...` to the above location. It again gives me the error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
ionic.io.bundle.min.js:2`.

The official website has acknowledged this problem and have posted the message:

> We have prioritized adding support for Ionic 2, but as it stands you
>   will get errors when trying to add the platform web client into an
>   Ionic 2 project.

Is there any method by which we can make this work in Ionic 2.